# Storing time series data in HDF5 with extendable time dimension

Tags: fortran, time-series, hdf5

I would like to store time series data in HDF5 with an extendable time dimension. I’m struggling at the final step of writing (appending) an additional data portion to the dataset.

The main data structure in my code is a 3D array of `beads`. The first dimension of an array is the Cartesian coordinate, the second---is the bead ID and the third---is the time frame index. I can successfully write this array into a dataset. The second part of the code is creating data for an additional one time frame, extends the existing dataset and attempts to write (append) the new single time frame data to the extended dataset. Would you please point me in the right direction? I suspect I have a mistake in the `hyperslab` selection. Maybe something is wrong with the `offset` or the `count` of the elements?

Example code:

```
  PROGRAM H5_ARR_BEADS_EXT

  USE HDF5

  IMPLICIT NONE

  ! No. of coordinates, beads, time frames
  integer, parameter :: NX = 3, NB = 10, NF = 5

  ! Beads array
  real, allocatable :: beads(:,:,:)

  ! Coordinate arrays
  real, allocatable :: gxx(:), gxy(:), gxz(:)

  ! File
  integer(hid_t)   :: fileID
  character(len=8) :: fileName = "data.h5"

  ! Dataspace
  integer          :: spaceRank    =   2
  integer(size_t)  :: spaceDims(2) = [NF, NB]  ! frame, bead
  integer(hsize_t) :: maxSpaceDims(2)
  integer(hid_t)   :: spaceID

  ! Memory space
  integer          :: memRank
  integer(hsize_t) :: memDims(2)
  integer(hid_t)   :: memID

  ! Hyperslab
  integer(hsize_t) :: offset(2), count(2)

  ! Datatype
  integer         :: arrTypeRank    =  1
  integer(size_t) :: arrTypeDims(1) = [NX]
  integer(hid_t)  :: arrTypeID, arrTypeWriteID

  ! Dataset
  integer(size_t)   :: dataSetDims(3) = [NF, NB, NX]  ! frame, bead, coord
  integer(hid_t)    :: dataSetID
  character(len=64) :: dataSetName
  integer(hsize_t)  :: dataSetExtDims(3)

  ! Property
  integer(hid_t)   :: propID
  integer(hsize_t) :: chunkDims(2)

  integer :: info  ! I/O status
  integer :: b, f  ! counters


  !              coord,         bead,          frame
  allocate(beads(dataSetDims(3),dataSetDims(2),dataSetDims(1)),           &
           gxx(dataSetDims(2)), gxy(dataSetDims(2)), gxz(dataSetDims(2)), &
           stat=info)

  ! Initialise Fortran interface
  call H5open_f(info)

  ! Create new file (with default properties)
  call H5Fcreate_f(fileName, H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, fileID, info)

  !-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ! Initialise data
  !   for each time frame
  do f = 1, NF

    ! Initialise data arrays
    call random_number(gxx)
    call random_number(gxy)
    call random_number(gxz)

    !   for each bead
    do b = 1, NB

      beads(:,b,f) = [gxx(b), gxy(b), gxz(b)]
      print *, "Bead(",b,",",f,"):", beads(:,b,f)

    end do
  end do

  ! Create 2D array dataspace (frame, bead) with
  ! unlimited time frame dimension
  ! maxSpaceDims = [H5S_UNLIMITED_F, spaceDims(2)]
  maxSpaceDims = [H5S_UNLIMITED_F, H5S_UNLIMITED_F]
  call H5Screate_simple_f(spaceRank, spaceDims, spaceID, info, maxSpaceDims)

  ! Enable chunking
  ! chunkDims = [int(1,8), spaceDims(2)]
  chunkDims = [int(1,8), int(1,8)]
  call H5Pcreate_f(H5P_DATASET_CREATE_F, propID, info)
  call H5Pset_chunk_f(propID, spaceRank, chunkDims, info)

  ! Create 1D array datatype (coord)
  call H5Tarray_create_f(H5T_NATIVE_REAL, arrTypeRank, arrTypeDims, &
                         arrTypeID, info)

  ! Create dataset with chunking property
  dataSetName = "Beads"
  call H5Dcreate_f(fileID, dataSetName, arrTypeID, spaceID, dataSetID, &
                   info, propID)

  ! Write data into file
  call H5Dwrite_f(dataSetID, arrTypeID, beads, dataSetDims, info)

  !-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  deallocate(beads, stat=info)

  !              coord,         bead,          frame
  allocate(beads(dataSetDims(3),dataSetDims(2),1), &
           stat=info)

  print *, ""
  print *, "----- ----- -----"
  print *, ""

  ! Empty data array
  beads = 0.0

  ! Initialise new data portion
  ! Initialise data arrays
  call random_number(gxx)
  call random_number(gxy)
  call random_number(gxz)

  !   for each bead
  do b = 1, NB

    beads(:,b,1) = [gxx(b), gxy(b), gxz(b)]
    print *, "Bead(",b,",",1,"):", beads(:,b,1)

  end do

  ! Extend dataset
  dataSetExtDims = [NF+1, NB, NX]
  call H5Dset_extent_f(dataSetID, dataSetExtDims, info)

  ! Create 2D array memory space (frame, bead)
  memRank = 2;  memDims = [1, NB]
  call H5Screate_simple_f(memRank, memDims, memID, info)

  ! Write to extended part of dataset
  !   Select hyperslab in dataspace
  offset = [NF, 0];   count = [1, NB]
  call H5Sselect_hyperslab_f(spaceID, H5S_SELECT_SET_F, offset, &
                             count, info)

  !   Write data
  dataSetDims = [1, NB, NX]
  call H5Dwrite_f(dataSetID, arrTypeID, beads(:,:,1), dataSetDims, info, &
                  memID, spaceID)

  ! Close dataset
  call H5Dclose_f(dataSetID, info)

  ! Close datatype
  call H5Tclose_f(arrTypeID, info)

  ! Close dataspace
  call H5Sclose_f(spaceID, info)

  ! Close memory space
  call H5Sclose_f(memID, info)

  !-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ! Close file
  call h5fclose_f(fileID, info)

  ! Close Fortran interface
  call h5close_f(info)

  ! Deallocate data arrays
  deallocate(beads, gxx, gxy, gxz, stat=info)

  END PROGRAM H5_ARR_BEADS_EXT
```

The code crashes with the following error messages:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
#000: ../../src/H5Dio.c line 322 in H5Dwrite(): could not get a validated dataspace from file_space_id
major: Invalid arguments to routine
minor: Bad value
#001: ../../src/H5S.c line 254 in H5S_get_validated_dataspace(): selection + offset not within extent
major: Dataspace
minor: Out of range
```

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot illustrating how the dataset looks like (e.g. in HDFView) with the code that crashes your program disabled?

Comment: I looked through the code, and the orderings of the indices in the data and H5 seem to be the opposite, which is confusing to me. I would look into the ordering of the indices in the hyperslab, which looks like wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the posted code, the dataspace used to create the dataset (its identifier is in `spaceID`) is re-used to select the hyperslab in the file to write the additional frame to.  But the dataset has had its extents expanded since creation - the dataspace used to create the dataset is no longer consistent with the extended data space of the dataset.

Use an appropriate dataspace for the hyperslab selection operation and the subsequent write.  An appropriate dataspace can be obtained by using `H5Dget_space_f` on the dataset after you have increased the dataset's extents.

(There may be other problems with the indicies as well - but it is the re-use of the data space that is causing the reported errors.)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problems with my program:

- The order of elements should be: coordinates `(NX)`, beads `(NB)` and frames `(NF)` everywhere, e.g. `spaceDims = [NB, NF]` and `dataSetDims = [NX, NB, NF]`, etc.
- The data space needs to be closed and opened before appending new data.
- Prior to appending the data, a **dataspace** has to be extended, not a **dataset.**

Please find a corrected program below:

```
PROGRAM H5_ARR_BEADS_EXT

USE HDF5

IMPLICIT NONE

! No. of coordinates, beads, time frames
integer, parameter :: NX = 3, NB = 10, NF = 5

! Beads array
real, allocatable :: beads(:,:,:)

! Coordinate arrays
real, allocatable :: gxx(:), gxy(:), gxz(:)

! File
integer(hid_t)   :: fileID
character(len=8) :: fileName = "data.h5"

! Dataspace
integer          :: spaceRank    =   2
integer(size_t)  :: spaceDims(2) = [NB, NF]  ! bead, frame
integer(hsize_t) :: maxSpaceDims(2)
integer(hid_t)   :: spaceID

! Memory space
integer          :: memRank
integer(hsize_t) :: memDims(2)
integer(hid_t)   :: memID

! Hyperslab
integer(hsize_t) :: offset(2), count(2)

! Datatype
integer         :: arrTypeRank    =  1
integer(size_t) :: arrTypeDims(1) = [NX]
integer(hid_t)  :: arrTypeID, arrTypeWriteID

! Dataset
integer(size_t)   :: dataSetDims(3) = [NX, NB, NF]  ! coord, bead, frame
integer(hid_t)    :: dataSetID
character(len=64) :: dataSetName
integer(hsize_t)  :: dataSetExtDims(3)

! Property
integer(hid_t)   :: propID
integer(hsize_t) :: chunkDims(2)

integer :: info  ! I/O status
integer :: b, f  ! counters


!              coord,         bead,          frame
allocate(beads(dataSetDims(1),dataSetDims(2),dataSetDims(3)),           &
         gxx(dataSetDims(2)), gxy(dataSetDims(2)), gxz(dataSetDims(2)), &
         stat=info)

! Initialise Fortran interface
call H5open_f(info)

! Create new file (with default properties)
call H5Fcreate_f(fileName, H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, fileID, info)

!-----------------------------------------------------------------------

! Initialise data
!   for each time frame
do f = 1, NF

  ! Initialise data arrays
  call random_number(gxx)
  call random_number(gxy)
  call random_number(gxz)

  !   for each bead
  do b = 1, NB

    beads(:,b,f) = [gxx(b), gxy(b), gxz(b)]
    print *, "Bead(",b,",",f,"):", beads(:,b,f)

  end do
end do

! Create 2D array dataspace (frame, bead) with
! unlimited time frame dimension
! maxSpaceDims = [H5S_UNLIMITED_F, spaceDims(2)]
maxSpaceDims = [H5S_UNLIMITED_F, H5S_UNLIMITED_F]
call H5Screate_simple_f(spaceRank, spaceDims, spaceID, info, maxSpaceDims)

! Enable chunking
! chunkDims = [int(1,8), spaceDims(2)]
chunkDims = [int(1,8), int(1,8)]
call H5Pcreate_f(H5P_DATASET_CREATE_F, propID, info)
call H5Pset_chunk_f(propID, spaceRank, chunkDims, info)

! Create 1D array datatype (coord)
call H5Tarray_create_f(H5T_NATIVE_REAL, arrTypeRank, arrTypeDims, &
                       arrTypeID, info)

! Create dataset with chunking property
dataSetName = "Beads"
call H5Dcreate_f(fileID, dataSetName, arrTypeID, spaceID, dataSetID, &
                 info, propID)

! Write data into file
call H5Dwrite_f(dataSetID, arrTypeID, beads, dataSetDims, info)

! Close dataset
call H5Dclose_f(dataSetID, info)

! Close dataspace
call H5Sclose_f(spaceID, info)

!-----------------------------------------------------------------------

deallocate(beads, stat=info)

!              coord,         bead,          frame
allocate(beads(dataSetDims(1),dataSetDims(2),1), &
         stat=info)

print *, ""
print *, "----- ----- -----"
print *, ""

! Empty data array
beads = 0.0

! Initialise new data portion
! Initialise data arrays
call random_number(gxx)
call random_number(gxy)
call random_number(gxz)

!   for each bead
do b = 1, NB

  beads(:,b,1) = [gxx(b), gxy(b), gxz(b)]
  print *, "Bead(",b,",",1,"):", beads(:,b,1)

end do

! Get dataset
call H5Dopen_f(fileID, dataSetName, dataSetID, info)

! Extend space
spaceDims = [NB, NF+1]
call H5Dset_extent_f(dataSetID, spaceDims, info)

! Create 2D array memory space (frame, bead)
memRank = 2;  memDims = [NB, 1]
call H5Screate_simple_f(memRank, memDims, memID, info)

! Get space
call H5Dget_space_f(dataSetID, spaceID, info)

! Write to extended part of dataset
!   Select hyperslab in dataspace
offset = [0, NF];   count = [NB, 1]
call H5Sselect_hyperslab_f(spaceID, H5S_SELECT_SET_F, offset, &
                           count, info)

!   Write data
dataSetDims = [NX, NB, 1]
call H5Dwrite_f(dataSetID, arrTypeID, beads(:,:,1), dataSetDims, info, &
                memID, spaceID)

! Close dataset
call H5Dclose_f(dataSetID, info)

! Close datatype
call H5Tclose_f(arrTypeID, info)

! Close dataspace
call H5Sclose_f(spaceID, info)

! Close memory space
call H5Sclose_f(memID, info)

!-----------------------------------------------------------------------

! Close file
call h5fclose_f(fileID, info)

! Close Fortran interface
call h5close_f(info)

! Deallocate data arrays
deallocate(beads, gxx, gxy, gxz, stat=info)

END PROGRAM H5_ARR_BEADS_EXT
```